# Why can't I connect through socket

Tags: android, sockets

I'm making an android app that connects with PC. I'm using solution that I've found [HERE](http://codesmith.in/control-pc-from-android-app-using-java/)
When I try to connect with PC by giving exact IP adress everything works fine. Phone connects fast with PC or (when server on PC isn't running) I get info about unability to connect fast. Here is code:

```
 public class ConnectPhoneTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        boolean result = true;
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(params[0]);
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, Constants.SERVER_PORT);//Open socket on server IP and port
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("remotedroid", "Error while connecting", e);
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
    {
        isConnected = result;
        Toast.makeText(context,isConnected?"Connected to server!":"Error while connecting",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try {
            if(isConnected) {
                out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket
                        .getOutputStream())), true); //create output stream to send data to server
            }
        }catch (IOException e){
            Log.e("remotedroid", "Error while creating OutWriter", e);
            Toast.makeText(context,"Error while connecting",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to loop through IP adresses to find device that I am able to connect to it takes very long time, until timeout. Here is code:

```
 public class DevicesListTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,List<Device>>
 {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pb.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Device> doInBackground(String... params) {
        List<Device> devices=new ArrayList<Device>();
        String device_ip;

        Socket socket;
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            device_ip=params[0]+Integer.toString(i);
            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(device_ip);
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 8988);
                devices.add(new Device(device_ip,socket.getInetAddress().getHostName()));


            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("remotedroid", "Error while connecting", e);

            }

        }
        return devices;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Device> devices) {
        pb.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
        if(devices!=null)
        {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context,DevicesList.class);
            String[] devicesIPS = new String[devices.size()];
            String[] devicesNames = new String[devices.size()];
            for(int i=0;i<devices.size();i++)
            {
                devicesIPS[i]=devices.get(i).getIP();
                devicesNames[i]=devices.get(i).getName();
            }
            intent.putExtra("DEVICES_IPS",devicesIPS);
            intent.putExtra("DEVICES_NAMES",devicesNames);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(context,"nope",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }
}
```

I just change a little bit code from example I linked above. What is wrong with this code?

Exception I get is:

```
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.2 (port 8988): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
```

I get it while trying to connect to my PC, but I get this exception only while looping through adresses and not in first example. While using code from first example i get connected instantly. What's wrong wit that second bit of code that connection times out?

Answer (score 1):

You will get connect timeouts when you try to connect to IP addresses that don't exist. The default timeout is around a minute. If you're getting connect timeouts you can shorten them as follows:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(); // create an unconnected socket
int timeout = 5000; // in milliseconds, tune as required
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(serverAddr, 8989), timeout);
```

5 seconds is more than enough in most circumstances, you can work it down to 2-3 seconds, not less.

Comment: The thing is that i don't get connect timeouts while I use the first code example, like in tutorial that i linked. The problem is when I try to check many adresses in loop. Why does connect work in one instance and not in another?

Comment: The thing is that you don't get timeouts when the connections succeed, but when you loop through IP addresses you get connect timeouts for the ones that don't exist, and they take a minute to expire. I've already stated all that.

Comment: I get timeout only while connecting to my PC. When IP isn't used I get info about it instantly

Comment: That is the opposite of what it says in your question, and it also doesn't make sense. You can't *not* get a timeout when connecting to a non-existent IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the internet permissions in the Manifest file for the app? If not, then Android is sock-blocking you.

Comment: Yes I do have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`. When I have exact IP of PC I don't have any connection problems. Problem starts when I loop throough adresses